# Can the holiday hats stay until at least Christmas Day?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

Re: http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

The holiday hats from the winter bash 2013 are so awesome, I especially love *The Stallman* one!

However, I've noticed that they are scheduled to expire on January 4th, 2014, I presume [New Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Style_and_New_Style_dates).

Any chance of them being kept until at least December 25, 2013, Old Style?

Comment: @icktoofay http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Style_and_New_Style_dates

Comment: It might be useful for those of us who have *absolutely no idea what the hell Old Style is* to include what the New Style equivalent would be.

Comment: @animuson, it'd be January 7, 2014

Comment: Jan 7? Excellent, I'd love to wear my hats on my name day.

Comment: I am wearing two hats.

Comment: I really have no intention of reading a Wikipedia article to understand what this meta post is about. What are you suggesting? Please use whatever style everybody here uses (UTC).

Comment: What @AsheeshR said. Also, unless a mob of MSOers with pitchforks upvotes this post and argues vehemently for it, we're very unlikely to change the end date of the event.